# Preview scans on Ubuntu 18.04 receive resolution errors

Tags: networking, scanner, epson, xsane

I can scan from my WF-2830 all-in-one. I have installed the imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-18.04-3.62.0.x64.deb driver from the Epson website. I edited the `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf` as follows:

```
myscanner.udi    = esci:networkscan://10.0.0.206:1865
myscanner.vendor = Epson
myscanner.model  = WF-2830
```

After selecting the above esci scanner from xsane's list, it accesses the scanner but gives, "Failed to set value of option x-resolution: Invalid argument," and  "Failed to set value of option y-resolution: Invalid argument" when acquiring a preview..  However, after closing the error windows, it does deliver a preview image and a scanned (with xsane's scan button) image.  Why the error messages?  How do I get rid of them?

I do not know how to specify the x- and -y resolution in the .conf file.

Searching the files listed by dpkg -L imagescan does not find any files containing x-resolution or y-resolution.

I recently noticed that the resolution field of the xsane window has the resolutions set to 75PPI, and they are grayed out.  Would this have anything to do with the messages appearing?

On the Advanced Options screen there is a checkbox for Bind X and Y resolutions.  I discovered that **anytime** this is checked, you will receive the error messages.  However, if not checked, the preview proceeds without error.  Furthermore, when not checked, the resolutions in the main xsane screen are ungrayed and selectable from a menu that pops up when the up/down button of the resolution is clicked.  Finally, regardless of the value set (I tested with 100 and 50), checking the Bind... checkbox sets you up to receive the error messages during Preview.  I consider these facts to be sufficient to answer my question, but am unable to post this information as a formal Answer.  So, I put it in this paragraph, hopefully, to benefit others.

Comment: Can you specify the x- and -y resolution in the `.conf` file?

Comment: Try `dpkg -L imagescan` to list all the files in the package. Find the ones that mention "x-resolution" and "y-resolution".